# Split an array of common English words into separate lists/arrays based on word length in Java

Tags: java, regex, arrays, list

I'm trying to search an array of common English words to see if a specific word is contained in it, based on a text file. Since this array has >700,000 words and around 1000 words need to be checked if in the array multiple times, I thought it would be more efficient to separate the words into separate arrays or lists based on length. Is there an easy way to do this without using a switch or lots of if statements? Like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < commonWordArray.length; i++) {
    if(commonWordArray[i].length == 2) {
        twoLetterList.add(commonWordArray[i]);
    else if(commonWordArray[i].length == 3) {
        threeLetterList.add(commonWordArray[i]);
    else if(commonWordArray[i].length == 4) {
        fourLetterList.add(commonWordArray[i]);
    }
    ...etc
}
```

Then doing the same thing when checking the words:

```
for(int i = 0; i < checkWords.length; i++) {
    if(checkWords[i].length == 2) {
        if(twoLetterList.contains(checkWords[i])) {
        ...etc
}
```

Comment: as storing large array in memory might be a killer, and constatn access to files might slow you wodn, why you dont want to store your words in database (ie H2) and just run simple query?

Comment: Does Java support hashes or associative array's ? If so, why not just create a key hash of the words, makes it easy for lookup. Or, are you allowing for substrings of specific words?

Comment: @user902383 I do agree that is a better way but this is for a simple cryptanalysis tool for my research paper, where the common words file can be passed as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**

Create word buckets.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> buckets = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < maxWordLength; i++) {
    buckets.add(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

**Step 2**

Add words to your buckets.

```
buckets.get(word.length()).add(word);
```

This approach has the downside that some of your buckets may go unused. This is not an issue if you are only filtering **common** English words, as they do not exceed 30 characters in length. Creating 10-15 extra lists is a trivial overhead for a computer. The largest uncommon but non-technical word is 183 characters. Technical words exceed 180,000 characters, by which point this approach is clearly not practical.

The upside of this approach is that `ArrayList.get()` and `ArrayList.add()` both run in constant (O(1)) time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `List<Set<String>> sets`. That is, given a `String word`, find first the proper set (`Set<String> set = sets.get(word.length)`) - create the set if needed, extend the list if needed. Then just do a `set.add(word)`. Done!

Edit/Hint: a (good) programmer should be lazy - if you need to do/write the same thing twice, you're doing *something* wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got memory for it (which your current approach relies on), why not just a single `Set<String>`?    Simpler, faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple strings to search, you may want to try something like the [Aho Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) algorithm.

Alternatively, you may want to turn the problem around and check if a string from the 700k array is in the 1k array. To this, you won't have memory issues (imho) and you may do it with a simple dictionary (balanced tree). so you'd have 700k log2(1000).

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), which is a memory-efficient storage mechanism which excels at storing words and checking for whether they exist or not.

Implementing one on your own is a fun exercise, or look at existing implementations.